# How to auto start an app in Android ICS and onwards?

Tags: android

I need to auto start an application after Installation (First Time) in ICS and onwards .
I know in prior version ,Boot completed receiver was working fine but In ICS and onwards version ,when an app is first installed but not started ,no broadcast receivers or services will run until after it is started

Comment: Did you know that Android Lost is working fine under these conditions. I'm also desperately looking how those guys are doing that!

Comment: Is it ...I would check Android Lost app. Thanks